# Query Spark SQL from Node.js server

Tags: node.js, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently using npm's [cassandra-driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cassandra-driver) to query my Cassandra database from a Node.js server. Since I want to be able to write more complex queries, I'd like to use Spark SQL instead of CQL. Is there any way to create a RESTful API (or something else) so that I can use Spark SQL the same way that I currently use CQL?

In other words, I want to be able to send a Spark SQL query from my Node.js server to another server and get a result back.

Is there any way to do this? I've been searching for solutions to this problem for a while and haven't found anything yet.

**Edit:** I'm able to query my database with Scala and Spark SQL from the Spark shell, so that bit is working. I just need to connect Spark and my Node.js server somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and I solved by using [Spark-JobServer](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver).

The main approach with Spark-Jobserver (SJS) usually is to create a special job that extends their SparkSQLJob such as in the following example:

```
object ExecuteQuery extends SparkSQLJob {
  override def validate(sqlContext: SQLContext, config: Config): SparkJobValidation = {
    // Code to validate the parameters received in the request body
  }
  override def runJob(sqlContext: SQLContext, jobConfig: Config): Any = {
    // Assuming your request sent a { "query": "..." } in the body:
    val df = sqlContext.sql(config.getString("query"))
    createResponseFromDataFrame(df) // You should implement this
  }
}
```

However, for this approach to work well with Cassandra, you have to use the [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) and then, to load the data you will have two options:

**1)** Before calling this `ExecuteQuery` via REST, you have to transfer the full data you want to query from Cassandra to Spark. For that, you would do something like (*code adapted from the [spark-cassandra-connector documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md)*):

```
val df = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map( "table" -> "words", "keyspace" -> "test"))
  .load()
```

And then register it as a table in order to SparkSQL be able to access it:

```
df.registerAsTempTable("myTable") // As a temporary table
df.write.saveAsTable("myTable") // As a persistent Hive Table
```

Only after that you would be able to use the `ExecuteQuery` to query from `myTable`.

**2)** As the first option can be inefficient in some use cases, there is another option.

The spark-cassandra-connector has a special [CassandraSQLContext](http://datastax.github.io/spark-cassandra-connector/ApiDocs/1.6.0-M2/spark-cassandra-connector/#org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext) that can be used to query C* tables directly from Spark. It can be used like:

```
val cc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
val df = cc.sql("SELECT * FROM keyspace.table ...")
```

However, to use a different type of context with Spark-JobServer, you need to extend `SparkContextFactory` and use it in the moment of context creation (which can be done by a POST request to `/contexts`). An example of a special context factory can be seen on [SJS Gitub](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/v0.6.2/job-server-extras/src/spark.jobserver/context/SQLContextFactory.scala). You also have to create a `SparkCassandraJob`, extending `SparkJob` (but this part is very [easy](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/v0.6.2/job-server-extras/src/spark.jobserver/SparkSqlJob.scala)).

Finally, the `ExecuteQuery` job have to be adapted to use the new classes. It would be something like:

```
object ExecuteQuery extends SparkCassandraJob {
  override def validate(cc: CassandraSQLContext, config: Config): SparkJobValidation = {
    // Code to validate the parameters received in the request body
  }
  override def runJob(cc: CassandraSQLContext, jobConfig: Config): Any = {
    // Assuming your request sent a { "query": "..." } in the body:
    val df = cc.sql(config.getString("query"))
    createResponseFromDataFrame(df) // You should implement this
  }
}
```

After that, the `ExecuteQuery`job can be executed via REST with a POST request.

---

**Conclusion**

Here I use the first option because I need the advanced queries available in the `HiveContext` (window functions, for example), which are not available in the `CassandraSQLContext`. However, if you don't need those kind of operations, I recommend the second approach, even if it needs some extra coding to create a new ContextFactory for SJS.